# Detect if activity is running from library

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I am using in my application(App A), another application(App B) connected as .dll. I must show Toast message when the App B(.dll) is exit. How can i detect this?

Comment: What do you mean by is exit?

Comment: I mean, when i close the library( activity from this library)

Comment: how can you close library ?

Comment: Its diffrent ways to close library. I can press back button(it returns to AppA). I can press close button in AppB. But the problem is, that i don't have acess to App B source code. I must operate only on App A code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get a write handler on .dll file.
If you get an exception, that mean the app `B` is still running,
If it's free that mean application `B` closed.

You can add a scheduler that will do polling of this check every x seconds.